# Group similar feed items in activity log

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-by

I am using Codeigniter and I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+-------+------+-----------+--------------+
| id | user  | post |  action   |    added     |
+----+-------+------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | ann   |    1 | commented | <date added> |
|  2 | sarah |    1 | commented | <date added> |
|  3 | carol |    1 | liked     | <date added> |
|  4 | susan |    1 | commented | <date added> |
|  5 | derek |    2 | liked     | <date added> |
|  6 | ann   |    1 | liked     | <date added> |
+----+-------+------+-----------+--------------+
```

On the activity feed I have all the posts outputting based on time. Most recent first.

Ann liked post 1
Derek liked post 2
Susan commented on post 1
carol liked post 1
sarah commented on post 1
ann commented on post 1

How is the best way to group these by activity on a post?
eg.

Ann and 1 other person liked post 1
Derek liked post 2
Susan and 2 other people commented on post 1

Am I best to get all of the information from the database and then sort it by php before the page loads? or do I perform some sort of GroupBy in the query?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no codeigniter expert but using a raw sql query you can do this rather easily. Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM activity_feed_table_name GROUP BY post";
```

I'm checking the codeigniter docs and its active record implementation supports the groupBy clause.

```
$this->db->get('yourActivityFeedTable');->group_by("post");
```

I haven't used CI in quite a while so I don't remember exactly the syntax but this might get you on the right track. Let us know if it works!